# Chamar arquivo externo pela Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, java, actionscript-3, div

No script abaixo é possível chamar um arquivo externo através dessa `<div>`

```
<div id="script" class="#"></div>
```

Observem nesse trecho  do script:

`https://'+id+'?=`

como faço para que através da `<div>`

```
<div id="script" class="#">
</div>
```

especialmente a parte `class="#"` seja a  área responsável para chamar a '+id+' do script

Aqui está o script:

```
function (obj) {
    document.getElementById('script').appendChild(get_embed(obj['feed']['media']['content']));
}

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://'+id+'?'+(Math.round(ts/3600)).toFixed();

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou capturar o ID desta maneira? Se só existir uma `<div>` com este ID, este é o jeito mais fácil de fazer.

```
function picasa_callback(obj) {
    document.getElementById('script').appendChild(get_embed(obj['feed']['media']['content']));
}

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

// Adicione ESTA linha para capturar o ID desejado:
var id = document.getElementById('script').className;

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https:/'+id+'?'+(Math.round(ts/3600)).toFixed();

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

---

Comment: desculpe, consegui fazer agora, tinha um codigo a mais no script, valeu pela ajuda